# Android Hilt dagger inject interface in viewModel @ViewModelInject got UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I trying on Hilt codelab
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-hilt#10

It's working fine with Activity and Fragment

logger is a RoomDB

Then I try to inject logger into viewModel with this [article](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/injecting-viewmodel-with-dagger-hilt-54ca2e433865)

By add

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel
    :1.0.0-alpha02"
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

ViewModelCode

```
class RecordFragmentViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(@Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) :
    ViewModel() {
    @DatabaseLogger
    @Inject
    lateinit var logger: LoggerDataSource
```

Class logger to inject

```
 class LoggerLocalDataSource 
@Inject constructor(private val logDao: LogDao) : LoggerDataSource {
```

LoggingModule

```
@Qualifier
annotation class InMemoryLogger

@Qualifier
annotation class DatabaseLogger

@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class LoggingDatabaseModule {

    @DatabaseLogger
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDatabaseLogger(impl: LoggerLocalDataSource): LoggerDataSource
}

@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class LoggingInMemoryModule {

    @InMemoryLogger
    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindInMemoryLogger(impl: LoggerInMemoryDataSource): LoggerDataSource
}
```

DatabaseModule

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "logging.db"
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideLogDao(database: AppDatabase): LogDao {
        return database.logDao()
    }
}
```

It's compile and run without error.
However, I use debug to watch logger and its got.

```
Method threw 'kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException' exception.
```

I call logger.something() at run time its throw

```
Fatal Exception: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
lateinit property logger has not been initialized
```

More info
https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide.html

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-hilt#10

https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/injecting-viewmodel-with-dagger-hilt-54ca2e433865

Comment: What happens when you change the injection of your database logger from field injection to constructor injection? You could also write `class RecordViewModel (@DataBaseLogger private val logger: LoggerDataSource ...)`. Also try adding @Singleton to your DAO

Comment: @Andrew not work its Unresolved reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since LoggerDataSource is a interface we need to specify which implementation we need to inject. Thanks to @Andrew for the idea of inject to constructor

```
class RecordFragmentViewModel
@ViewModelInject
constructor(@Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
            @DatabaseLogger private val logger: LoggerDataSource) :
    ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {
```

To specify

```
@Qualifier
annotation class InMemoryLogger

@Qualifier
annotation class DatabaseLogger

@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class LoggingDatabaseModule {

    @DatabaseLogger
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindDatabaseLogger(impl: LoggerLocalDataSource): LoggerDataSource
}

@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class LoggingInMemoryModule {

    @InMemoryLogger
    @ActivityScoped
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindInMemoryLogger(impl: LoggerInMemoryDataSource): LoggerDataSource
}
```

Comment: Now `@ViewModelInject` and `ApplicationComponent::class` are both deprecated so If we use `@HiltViewmodel`  and replace `ApplicationComponent' with `Singltoncomponent`  then how to use this?